# does anyone know where to get source code for Subsonic 2.0.2.0?

Tags: subsonic

I have an application that will be utilizing Ingrian's database encryption and it doesn't support `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. This must be changed to `@@IDENTITY`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

URL: https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-2.0

Comment: I had pulled that down. Unfortunately it's not the same version (this one is 2.2.1), but it's better than nothing. I guess I will get to work on refactoring.